# Good or Bad for SEO: Keeping URLs in English for a non-english website?

Tags: url, internationalization, seo

I'm planning to release a community website that doesn't have a PRIMARY audience that is english speaking. This means that URLs that point to /profile /forums and so on will be in english and not in their native language. I'm not concerned if a user is using the website while accessing different URL paths in English, but I am concerned if I were to use non english URLs then would a search engine pickup on pages on the website better or worse?

Anyone care to share their opinions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, it would be better to have URLs that reflect the primary language of your users as it would make them finding your website easier on search engines (supposing they search using their primary language). From a SEO perspective, if possible try to also include in your URLs the relevant search terms you think would be used by your audience. If you have a forum, for example, include in the thread URLs the full thread title if possible, and so on.

Sources: my own experience with building and managing [powershell.it](http://powershell.it) and [sqlserver.it](http://sqlserver.it), two of the most important Italian technology-related communities.

Comment: This is good. Sorry for replying to it so late. Is it better to have two sets of URLs (one for each language)? Or just have the URLs designed after primary language of the website?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start on this issue would be Google's [Webmaster Central section on Internationalization](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-internationalisation).

If you will have versions of the same URL in multiple languages, you can connect them using the `rel="alternate"`mechanism, which is explained at Google's [Webmaster Tools page](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077).

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Summary

Using non-English URLs for non-English websites is fine.

---

### 2. Argumentation

> Google Senior Webmaster Trends Analyst John Mueller said in a recent [**SEO snippets video**](https://searchengineland.com/seo-snippets-new-google-video-series-help-webmasters-seos-288728) that using non-English URLs for non-English websites is fine and that Google is able to crawl, index and rank them.
>
> This includes non-Latin characters in your URLs. John Mueller said “as long as URLs are valid and unique, that’s fine.” He added, “So to sum it up, yes, non-English words and URLs are fine, and we recommend using them for non-English websites.”

Read full article [**here**](https://searchengineland.com/google-using-non-english-urls-non-english-websites-fine-294758).

---

### 3. Disclaimer

Data of this answer were relevant in March 2018 and may be obsolete in the future.